# How to find capacity of an SD card plugged in to your Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, sd-card, hardware-detection

How can I find the capacity (in MB or GB) of an SD card plugged in to a Windows 7 PC?

Comment: @gronostaj: Sorry, yes, should have mentioned all that. Thanks for pointing it out. Knew about it (to try first and mention findings, etc.) but forgot. I had  googled for phrases similar to my question here. Did not try many variations  on phrases. From results I saw, did not find an answer that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 3):

1) Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then write `diskmgmt.msc` into the appearing window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the now appearing Device Management, you can see all your storage devices.

2) Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then write `cmd.exe` into the appearing window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the now appearing Command Prompt, write `wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption` and again press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now, an information table will show up with information about your storage devices.

Comment: bad command, devmgmt.msc to diskmgmt.msc, didn't notice my error, thanks.

Comment: Vieiros: Thanks. I did command 2) and got this:  
C:> wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption  
Caption  FreeSpace    Size  
C:       4295716864   104752738304  
D:       20694999040  104857595904  
E:       0            70035456   
F:   
G:    
H:       75120640     104853504

Comment: Also had run your command 1). Neither 1) nor 2) seems to show info that I can detect to be about SD card. I now suspect that there is no card in  card slot on laptop. There is some plastic thing in the slot, but I think it may not be a card, maybe just a placeholder sort of thing. I bought laptop a few years ago, so don't remember whether a real SD card came with it. Don't know whether such a thing (placeholder) is possible or not, since had never used SD cards before. Will google about it. Any info appreciated though.

Comment: @MydnyghtRyder yes, there are placeholders around - usually, they don't have the necessary metal contact areas ("pins") on the front end, so they are 100% plastic.

Comment: Laptops don't come with SD cards included (that wouldn't quite make sense). There's usually a dummy plastic "card" in the slot. It has no label like real SD cards.

Comment: @flolilolilo:  Yes, good point, should have thought of it myself - about the fact that plastic placeholders would not have metal contact pins - checked now, it does not have them, so it must be a placeholder.

Comment: @gronostaj: Don't see why it would not make sense (e.g. how about a "fully loaded laptop") - at least in some cases. But thanks for the reply. Appreciate the point about no label.

Comment: @MydnyghtRyder because your laptop already comes with a hard disk which has 10 times the capacity of SD card and is at least 10 times as fast.

Comment: @gronostaj: Got it, thanks. Yes, does not make sense to add a small amount of extra storage via SD card in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `My Computer` - select the disk and right click and select properties - this will show you the used space, the free space and the total space.

If it's not showing under `My Computer` it's possibly not been formatted yet, so you can also get this infomation from `Disk Management` - find this under system tools in the start menu, or in the control panel.

Comment: Disk Management in Control Panel leads to same window as diskmgmt.msc suggested by Vieiros.